# Access this. of parent function within a function in JS

Tags: javascript

I think the question title sums it up pretty well, if not, let me explain:

I have a class, that one has a function and inside that function A I NEED to have another function (function B), which needs to access a variable of function A. I hope this is enough, I really can not find any better words of how to describe this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+access+variable+from+other+function+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What you "think" you really need may not actually be real. Better ask for your root problem instead of asking about a proposed solution to avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: As suggested by @ZloiGoroh below, you can convert your inner function to an `arrow funtion`. Then you will be able to access variables defined in your parent function from arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need arrow functions for that

```
class Some() {
    constructor() {
        /* ... */
    }
    A(params) {
        let localVariable = 1
        const B = () => {
            // here you can access to the context (this)
            // and to A local variables (params, localVariable )
        }
    }
}
```

If i understood you correctly. And please ask more specific questions next time. Also try to share your code. It would be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a design problem. It sounds like you're attempting to break variable scoping rules. It seems to me, that this is what you're trying to do:

```
class some_class {
    A_function() {
      let variable1 = 5;
    }
    B_function() {
      let variable1 = 10;
    }
}
```

'variable1' is defined in A_function and is not accessible to B_function because of scoping rules. In fact, the variable1 in A_function and the variable1 in B_function are different variables.

However, a better implementation, that would likely work as you intend would be more like this:

```
class some_class {
    constructor() {
        this.variable1 = 5;
    }
    A_function() {
        this.variable1 = 10;
    }
    B_function() {
        this.variable1 = 15;
    }
}
```

Now, this.variable1 is defined as a property of the class and is accessible to both functions. Either function can modify the value of the variable.

Is this what you have in mind?